# EXCEL VBA: How to Programmatically Change .Placement Property of a Chart by Name

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have the following code where I am attempting to change the .Placement property of a chart entitled "MyChart".

[image]

The highlighted line results in an error stating "The item with the specified name was not found."

As you can see from the picture, I also tried:

```
MyChart.Placement = xlFreeFloating
```

However, it is my understanding that .Placement is a property of a ChartObject and not a Chart itself.

Here is the code from the pic above:

```
 'Format Main Title
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"

  'Set FreeFloating Property
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart").Placement = xlFreeFloating

  'MyChart.Placement = xlFreeFloating
```

How can I change the .Placement property for MyChart (that is, How can I change the .Placement property for a particular chart by name)? Any assistance is appreciated.

===========================================================================

In response to the solution offered: When I try this code, I get this error message:

[image]

[image]

I don't understand how the name of the graph could be anything but "MyChart". Here is the code that creates this graph:

```
Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(Left:=Cells(Row0 + (j3 - 1) * 22, Col0 + ChartStart + 1 + (k3 - 1) * 7).Left, _
                        Top:=Cells(Row0 + (j3 - 1) * 22, Col0 + ChartStart + 1 + (k3 - 1) * 7).Top, _
                        Width:=310, _
                        Height:=300).Chart

                    MyChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter
                    MyChart.HasLegend = False

                    With MyChart
                        'XAxis Label
                        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = XName(i3, 1)
                        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"
                        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                        'YAxis Label
                        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = YName
                        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Bold = True
                        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"
                        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Font.Size = 10
                    End With

                    'Remove Gridlines
                    For Each axs In MyChart.Axes
                        axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
                        axs.HasMinorGridlines = False
                    Next

                    With MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                        .Name = "Scatterplot of " & YName & " by " & XName(i3, 1)
                        .Values = y5
                        .XValues = WorksheetFunction.Index(X4, 0, i3 + 1)
                        'Format Markers
                        .MarkerBackgroundColorIndex = 2
                        .MarkerForegroundColorIndex = 5
                        .MarkerStyle = 8
                    End With

                    '5% around the edges
                    'XXX 999

                    'Vertical Axes NOT at zeros

                    If WorksheetFunction.Min(WorksheetFunction.Index(X4, 0, i3 + 1)) < 0 Then
                        MyChart.Axes(xlCategory).CrossesAt = MyChart.Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).MinimumScale
                    End If

                    'Format Main Title
                    MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
                    MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
                    MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"

                    'Set FreeFloating Property
                    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("MyChart").Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating

                    'MyChart.Placement = xlFreeFloating


                    'Set FreeFloating Property
'                    ActiveChart.Select
'                    Selection.Placement = xlFreeFloating
```

Comment: MyChart is a chart variable. It is not the name of the chart or of the chart object. Just use `MyChart.Parent.Placement = xlFreeFloating`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 'Format Main Title
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Size = 14
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True
  MyChart.ChartTitle.Font.Name = "TimesNewRoman"

  'Set FreeFloating Property
  ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(MyChart.name).Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating

  'In mine this is running too
  'ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(MyChart.name).Placement = xlFreeFloating
```

but you must ensure the chart name is same as displayed in the left of formula bar

[image]

First method, compare mychart.name with ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.chart.Name and use ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

```
For Each thechart In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    If thechart.Chart.Name = myChart.Name Then
       myChartName = thechart.Name

       thechart.Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating

       Exit For
    End If
Next
```

Second method, use myChart.parent

```
  myChart.Parent.Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating
```

Comment: Thanks for the line of code. Unfortunately, I am still getting an error. I have revised the initial post with more info on the new line of code.

Comment: Looks like your chart name is different, usually the name chart is chart1, chart2 etc. As said on message error, indicated mychart is not found

Comment: Try to check the letter Case, compare your chart name displayed ini formula bar and in your script

Comment: Ok Info see, mychart is not your chart name, just variable

Comment: I modify my answer

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yes, I see the chart name in the formula bar now. My issue is that this code is part of a larger macro program that creates a varying number of graphs per sheet depending on user inputs. Therefore, I am trying to figure out how figure out what the chart name of each chart as it is created is. Ideas?

Comment: I have modified my answer, use mychart.name

Comment: When I use MyChart.Name, it returns the sheet name AND the chart name. For example: Sheet 1 Chart 1. Therefore I had to split the string. My code solution is posted. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I developed with the help of user11982...

MyChart.Name returns the sheet name and the chart name:

```
MyChart.Name = Sheet 1 Chart 2
```

Because I just want the chart name:

```
            txtary = Split(MyChart.Name, " ")
            ChartName = txtary(2) & " " & txtary(3)

            'Set FreeFloating Property
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ChartName).Placement = Excel.XlPlacement.xlFreeFloating
```